# Sending ASCII characters and int in the same UDP packet

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp

I need to send a packet via UDP socket in which there will be a six digit number written as ASCII string and after a new line character, same number but as `int` in bytes, like this: `31 32 33 34 35 36 0A 00 01 E2 40` which corresponds to `123456\n(123456)` - integer is in brackets. So far I can send my string and my newline char, but when it comes to an `int` I get that 0 bytes were written into the buffer and nothing from my `int` buffer array is sent. Additionally, if I check text content of `int` buffer array it has weird amount of "Fs": `00 01 FFFFFFE2 40`

This is my UDP client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>


char buf[11];

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_in adr;
    int sock, r;
    unsigned int port;
    char abcd[512];
    char intBuff[4];
    unsigned int index = 123456;
    unsigned int networkHost;
    networkHost = htonl(index);

    memcpy(intBuff, (char*)&networkHost,sizeof(uint32_t));
    printf("Int buffer: ");
      for(int i=0; i<sizeof(uint32_t); i++){
        printf("%02X ", intBuff[i]); //Output is 00 01 FFFFFFE2 40
    }

    int x1 = sprintf(buf,"%s\n","123456"); 
    printf("\n1st data write: %i\n", x1); //7 bytes are written


    int x2 = sprintf(&buf[x1], "%s",intBuff); 
    printf("2nd data write: %i\n", x2); //0 bytes are written


    //SERVER
    printf("IP: ");
    scanf("%s", abcd);
    printf("PORT: ");
    scanf("%u", &port);

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    adr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    adr.sin_port = htons(port);
    adr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(abcd);


    r = sendto(sock,
               buf,
               11,
               0,
               (struct sockaddr*) &adr,
               sizeof(adr));

    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem

The strange value occurs because your array of `char` is `signed`, and the compiler interprets it as `signed` integer when you pass it to `printf`.

Do not use `sprintf(...,"%s", ...)` to copy binary data that potentially contains zero byte, because `"%s"` format will suddenly stop copying when it reaches `\0` null char.

---

### Solution

1. Use `unsigned char`, so the compiler does not interpret it as `signed` integer when it pass the data to `printf`.
2. Use `memcpy` to copy the `intBuff` to `buf`.

---

### Code example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main() {
    unsigned char buf[11];
    unsigned char intBuff[sizeof(uint32_t)];
    uint32_t index = 123456;
    uint32_t networkHost;
    networkHost = htonl(index);

    memcpy(intBuff, &networkHost, sizeof(networkHost));

    for (int i=0; i < sizeof(intBuff); i++){
      printf("%02x ", intBuff[i]);
    }

    int x1 = sprintf(buf,"%s\n","123456"); 
    printf("\n1st data write: %i\n", x1); // 7 bytes are written


    // It is certain that the write is sizeof(intBuff) in size.
    memcpy(&buf[x1], intBuff, sizeof(intBuff));

    int total_len = x1 + sizeof(intBuff);

    printf("Packed data: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < total_len; i++) {
      printf("%02x ", buf[i]);
    }

    putchar('\n');
}
```

### Output

```c
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ gcc x.c -o x 
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ ./x
00 01 e2 40 
1st data write: 7
Packed data: 31 32 33 34 35 36 0a 00 01 e2 40 
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$
```

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah, but at least it is relevant to weird data the OP said about "`00 01 FFFFFFE2 40`".

Comment: I adapted you answer and when I `printf()` my buffer at the end I get only "123456\n" and the second number does not appear, same goes for server, it prints only first number and newline. I don't know if its normal. Despite that the number of bytes sent is 11 and also bytes are right, so everything works fine.

Comment: @kapisolec Not only `sprintf`, `printf` also stops printing when it prints array of `char` and reaches zero byte. Now, you can see the data in hex "`31 32 33 34 35 36 0a 00 01 e2 40`". The part `00` is zero byte (null char). It only prints until `0a` which is `\n`. So this is very normal behavior.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your thorough answer!

Answer (score 1):

The bytes that represent an integer may, in general, have any values, as the integer takes on various values. So a byte may be zero. Then writing those bytes to a buffer using `printf` with `%s` will stop at the zero byte, because `%s` expects a string. The definition of a string is that it is a sequence of characters whose end is marked by a zero byte.

With the value you are using, the first byte is a zero, so `printf` stops immediately, and no bytes are written.

Instead of using `printf` to copy the bytes into the buffer, just copy them directly with `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(&buf[x1], &networkHost, sizeof networkHost);
```

You do not need `intBuff` at all and can remove it from your program.